'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' in asmx.cs file of asp.net c#
I have Two Input Type = "Date" and one Input Type = "Button"
<input type="date" runat="server" id="dtp_from" />
<input type="date" runat="server" id="dtp_to" />
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" CssClass="custom-btn" value="Submit" />

One GridView Table
<table id="gv_Datatable" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Receipt</th>
            <th>Payment</th>                            
            <th>Balance</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Receipt</th>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>Balance</th>                            
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>                

Now, here when click on button ajax method is called and through parameter two date are passing to the asmx.cs file.
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {                
    var dataToSend = {
        param1: JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("<%=dtp_from.ClientID%>").value),
        param2: JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("<%=dtp_to.ClientID%>").value)
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FillGridMethod.asmx/CashBookList",
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {                        
            var datatableVariable = $('#gv_Datatable').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'Id', visible: false },
                    {
                        'data': 'cashbookdate', 'render': function (date) {
                            var date = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
                            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                            return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                        }
                    },
                    { 'data': 'cashbookaccname' },
                    { 'data': 'cashbookdescription' },
                    { 'data': 'cashbookreceipt' },
                    { 'data': 'cashbookpayment' },
                    { 'data': 'Balance' },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) { return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-success' onclick=DeleteCustomer('" + row.Id + "');>View</>"; }
                    },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, row) { return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>"; }
                    }]
            });
        }
    });
});

Here is the asmx.cs file code
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
public void CashBookList(string param1, string param2)
{
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(param1, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var cashBook = new List<CashBookModel>();
    string constr = cn.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        qryFillGrid = " select cashbookid, cashbookdate, cashbookaccname, cashbookdescription, cashbookreceipt, cashbookpayment, Balance from tbl_cashbook " + System.Environment.NewLine;
        qryFillGrid += " where BranchID = " + HttpContext.Current.Session["BranchID"] + " " + System.Environment.NewLine;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["AccountMode"].ToString() != "ALL")
        {
            qryFillGrid += " and AccountMode = '" + HttpContext.Current.Session["AccountMode"].ToString() + "' " + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        if(param1 != "\"\"")
        {                    
            qryFillGrid += " and convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, cashbookdate,105),112) >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(service.IfNullThen(fromDate, DateTime.Now.Date)).Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            if (param2 != "\"\"")
            {
                qryFillGrid += " and convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, cashbookdate,105),112) <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(service.IfNullThen(param2, DateTime.Now.Date)).Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' " + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            qryFillGrid += " and convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, cashbookdate,105),112) = '" + System.DateTime.Now.Date + "' " + System.Environment.NewLine;                    
        }
        qryFillGrid += " order by cashbookdate, cashbookid desc " + System.Environment.NewLine;
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(qryFillGrid, con);
        con.Open();
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var cashBookModel = new CashBookModel
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                cashbookdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[1]),
                cashbookaccname = dr[2].ToString(),
                cashbookdescription = dr[3].ToString(),
                cashbookreceipt = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[4], 0)),
                cashbookpayment = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[5], 0)),
                Balance = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[6], 0)),
            };
            cashBook.Add(cashBookModel);
        }
    }
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(cashBook));
}

DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(param1, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
In this below line of asmx.as file getting error i.e.: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Debug your code and check what date format comes in the param1 parameter. you parsing DateTime.ParseExact. so param1 date value should be in the same 'dd/MM/yyyy' format. otherwise changes as param1 date formate in your Datetime.ParseExact.

@MalvikBhavsar in param1 date coming in "yyyy-MM-dd" format i.e.: "2024-05-01"

Change this line as: DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(param1, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

so, you pass in 2024-05-01 and tell ParseExact to expect dd/MM/yyyy ... yeah, can't see why that wouldn't work

@MalvikBhavsar Changed still showing same error.

@s.k.Soni
It should work. check this code.


Sir, I am checking in immediate windows then I  am getting this format ""2024-05-01""

So first correct your date string format for the same. It should be "2024-05-01", check your Ajax code. and correct for format.

Can you tell me how to get date value by javascript? so that I can pass that value from ajax

check this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_input_date_defaultvalue3


please do not use images of code but use formatted text, 2) please explain what you changed and why it "should work"


There is no need to address an answer to the OP, it's obvious that's who the answer is for. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your answer fixes it.
